# NetworkAddressChanged calls my callback just once

Tags: c#, events, .net-core

I'm trying to have a correct handlig for any changes in network in my application. I wrote a simple program to test how `NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged` and got some really weird results: if I subscribe this event, it's being called just once, but if I add and remove a subscribtion to an empty function, it starts working just fine (one call for plugging ethernet cable out and two for plugging in).

I've tried changing event causes, for example, changing my computer's ip on DHCP server and `ipconfig /renew`.
Target platform is `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Subscribing event
        NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += OnAddressChanged;
        //just a loop
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    //Callback
    static void OnAddressChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        foreach (NetworkInterface n in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0} is {1}", n.Name, n.OperationalStatus);
        }
        //Works if uncomment two lines below
        //NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += DuctTape;
        //NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged -= DuctTape;
    }
    //Empty function
    static void DuctTape(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce this in .Net Core, and it works as expected in a .Net framework project. Sounds like a bug, I would suggest  [raising an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues) and using your workaround until it's fixed.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for your answer, i've submitted an issue as you suggested.